# VB.Net Process.Start - Verb

Tags: vb.net, process.start

I want my vb.net Program to launch notepad and elevate the credentials however there is no prompt and the program just opens.

```
    Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = Nothing
    Dim processStartInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    processStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
    processStartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
    processStartInfo.Verb = "runas"

    processStartInfo.Arguments = ""
    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo)
```

Comment: at first glance the code should work. An explanation would be that the program you are opening your process from, is already Elevated (running as admin)

Comment: It appears that you are correct. Is it possible to force password even if admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of unnecessary code there.  You're using two lines to declare and set your two variables when you only need one each time.  You're setting the `FileName` property explicitly when you can pass an argument to the constructor and you're also setting three properties to their default values.  I just stripped it down to the bare minimum:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe") With {.Verb = "runas"}
Dim proc = Process.Start(psi)
```

When I ran that code from a new WinForms app with just a `Button` on the form and I got a UAC prompt as expected.

Comment: the above code opens notepad such as mine with the extra code however I am not getting the UAC code.

Comment: Can you right-click Notepad in File Explorer and get a UAC prompt? If so then, as mentioned earlier by another member, that seems to suggest something about the process executing that code. You could try building an EXE and running that rather than running it in the debugger, if you haven't already. You could also try running that EXE under a limited user account, so you know for a fact that you should get a UAC prompt.